Xero Authentication App - The app logs in perfectly, but does not get redirected to the next page after logging in
I built an Authentication app that lets you click a button a which takes you to a login screen which you will then need to log into your Xero account and then you get take to the page which asks you in which organization you want to work. Everything works perfect until then, but thereafter it takes me back to the screen with the login button and I do not know why.
XeroOauth2Controller.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Newtonsoft.Json; // For JSON serialization and deserialization
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Config;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Client;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Token;

public class XeroOauth2Controller : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<XeroOauth2Controller> _logger;
    private readonly XeroConfiguration _xeroConfig;

    public XeroOauth2Controller(ILogger<XeroOauth2Controller> logger, IOptions<XeroConfiguration> xeroConfig)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _xeroConfig = xeroConfig.Value;
    }

    // Initiates the login and redirects to Xero login page
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var client = new XeroClient(_xeroConfig);
        var loginUri = client.BuildLoginUri();

        return Redirect(loginUri.ToString());
    }

    // Callback after Xero redirects back with the authorization code
    public async Task<IActionResult> Callback(string code, string state)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            _logger.LogError("Authorization code not found in the callback request.");
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
        }

        var client = new XeroClient(_xeroConfig);

        try
        {
            // Exchange the authorization code for a full token (access + refresh tokens)
            var xeroToken = (XeroOAuth2Token)await client.RequestAccessTokenAsync(code);

            if(xeroToken == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Failed to retrieve the token");
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
            }

            // Serialize the token and store it in cookies
            var tokenJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xeroToken);
            Response.Cookies.Append("XeroToken", tokenJson, new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = true
            });

            var cookieExists = Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("XeroToken");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Cookie exists: {cookieExists}");

            _logger.LogInformation("Access and refresh tokens stored successfully.");
            return RedirectToAction("GetOrganizations", "Home");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error occurred while requesting access token: " + ex.Message);
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
        }
    }

    // Refresh the access token using the refresh token
    public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshToken()
    {
        // Retrieve the serialized token from the cookie
        var tokenJson = Request.Cookies["XeroToken"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenJson))
        {
            _logger.LogError("Xero token is missing or invalid.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "XeroOauth2"); // Redirect to login if no token is found
        }

        // Deserialize the XeroOAuth2Token object
        var xeroToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XeroOAuth2Token>(tokenJson);

        var client = new XeroClient(_xeroConfig);

        try
        {
            // Pass the entire token object to refresh the access token
            var newToken = await client.RefreshAccessTokenAsync(xeroToken);

            // Serialize and store the new token
            var newTokenJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newToken);
            Response.Cookies.Append("XeroToken", newTokenJson, new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = true
            });

            _logger.LogInformation("Access token refreshed successfully.");
            return RedirectToAction("GetOrganizations", "Organizations");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error occurred while refreshing token: {ex.Message}");
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
        }
    }
}


Homecontroller.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using XeroOAuth2._0_V3_.Models;

namespace XeroOAuth2._0_V3_.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}


OrganizationsController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Config;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Api;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Client;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Token;

public class OrganizationsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<OrganizationsController> _logger;
    private readonly XeroConfiguration _xeroConfig;

    public OrganizationsController(ILogger<OrganizationsController> logger, IOptions<XeroConfiguration> xeroConfig)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _xeroConfig = xeroConfig.Value;
    }

    // Fetch and display organizations
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrganizations()
    {
        // Retrieve the serialized token from the cookie
        var tokenJson = Request.Cookies["XeroToken"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenJson))
        {
            _logger.LogError("Access token is missing. Redirecting to login.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "XeroOauth2"); // Redirect to login if no access token is found
        }

        // Deserialize the XeroOAuth2Token object
        var xeroToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XeroOAuth2Token>(tokenJson);

        try
        {
            // Create an instance of AccountingApi to fetch organizations
            var accountingApi = new AccountingApi();

            // Get the organizations associated with the access token
            var response = await accountingApi.GetOrganisationsAsync(xeroToken.AccessToken, xeroToken.Tenants[0].TenantId.ToString());

            // Pass the organizations to the view
            return View(response._Organisations);
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error occurred while fetching organizations: " + ex.Message);
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
        }
    }
}


Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Config;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Client;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Add configuration options from appsettings.json for Xero OAuth2
builder.Services.Configure<XeroConfiguration>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("XeroOAuth2"));

// Enable cookie authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/XeroOauth2/Index";
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication(); // Add authentication middleware
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();


This is the code I think is relevant. please let me know if any other code is needed.
When I run it, it logs in perfectly, but it is supposed to take show me the details of the organization afterwards. It rather still shows me the login button. I tried changing the redirect in the Callback method in the XeroOauth2Controller.cs, but it still takes me to the same page: the screen with the login button or the home page.
Screen I see after logging in:

